# Laravel custom method works in browser, but not in tinker. Why?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on the samples in the Easy Laravel Book by W. Jason Gilmore. I have the following method created based on the examples in the book:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('todoparrot\Category', 'category_todolist')->withTimestamps();
}
```

I then created my own custom method:

```
public function categorylist(){
    return $this->categories()->get()->lists('id')->all();
}
```

My custom method depends on the first one above. The reason, I created that method is because of a change in 5.1 that does not return the data in an array. I need the array in a separate file here:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Categories') !!}
    {!! Form::select('categories', $categories, $list->categorylist(), array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'categories[]')) !!}
</div>
```

Everything works fine in a browser, but I am wondering why I can not call categorylist() in tinker.

If I call categories(), I get this:

```
>>> $foo->categories()
=> <Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany #000000005647099500000001622e905d> {}
>>>
```

If I call categorylist(), I get this:

```
>>> $foo->categorylist()
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::categorylist()'
>>>
```

Why do I get a ***Call to undefined method*** error in Tinker when everything works in the browser as expected.

I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: FYI, you only need `return $this->categories()->lists('id');`. `all()` is redundant, and `lists()` does a `get()` that's limited to just the necessary data. The way you're doing does a `SELECT *` first which is inefficient.

Comment: `return $this->categories()->lists('id')`  Doesn't work. Also, as of 5.1 `all()` is needed to return the data as an array instead of a collection. I need the data as an array.

Comment: You can use `toArray` or `(array)$this...` for that, to make things clearer to others reading your code. What happens when you do `$this->categories()->lists('id')`?